# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 20.04, network-manager

System: Dell Precision T3400 dual-boot Windows 10/Ubuntu. The system is connected via Ethernet to the internet at the moment.
After update to Ubuntu 20.04 I am experiencing "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" when attempting to use the EDUP EP-AC1661 Wi-Fi adapter. I have downloaded the Linux driver for this adapter from http://www.szedup.com/ep-ac1661/, have extracted the archives and double-clicked on all of the install.sh files in the RTL8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.1_22211_COEX20170310-1212.20170517 folder. I have searched Synaptic forRTL8821CU but Synaptic returned: "Could not download all repository indexes"
I have tried following the suggestions from articles resulting from the search for "No Wi-Fi Adaper Found Ubuntu 20.04" sources to no avail, most likely due to my lack of expertise with Linux:

Output from "wireless-info.txt" follows:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Nov 2020 14:57 CST -0600

Booted last: 21 Nov 2020 00:00 CST -0600

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:167a] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Precision T3400 [1028:0214]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0461:0010 Primax Electronics, Ltd HP PR1101U / Primax PMX-KPR1101U Keyboard
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.84/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp4s0
       valid_lft 82672sec preferred_lft 82672sec
    inet6 2600:1700:67b2:36a0::47/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3524sec preferred_lft 3524sec
    inet6 fd2d:9091:5573:1:a903:bdb7:a9e5:ab4/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 6899sec preferred_lft 6899sec
    inet6 fd2d:9091:5573:1:5a74:a87b:36cd:ca46/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6899sec preferred_lft 6899sec
    inet6 2600:1700:67b2:36a0:a903:bdb7:a9e5:ab4/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3330sec preferred_lft 3330sec
    inet6 2600:1700:67b2:36a0:2f20:5b7d:8e25:350b/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3330sec preferred_lft 3330sec
    inet6 fe80::51fa:9873:3a0d:92e9/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp4s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.84 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search attlocal.net

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         795       1  0 10:18 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        NetXtreme BCM5754 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (Precision T3400)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tg3
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.137
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               5754-v3.24
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp4s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:04:00.0/net/enp4s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp4s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       6ab51d0b-c1ad-3105-9293-afaab89a26d1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.84/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.254
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.254, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.254
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          attlocal.net
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name = attlocal.net
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.254
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        expiry = 1606074945
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.84
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       routers = 192.168.1.254
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2600:1700:67b2:36a0::47/128
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2600:1700:67b2:36a0:a903:bdb7:a9e5:ab4/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fd2d:9091:5573:1:a903:bdb7:a9e5:ab4/64
IP6.ADDRESS[4]:                         2600:1700:67b2:36a0:2f20:5b7d:8e25:350b/64
IP6.ADDRESS[5]:                         fd2d:9091:5573:1:5a74:a87b:36cd:ca46/64
IP6.ADDRESS[6]:                         fe80::51fa:9873:3a0d:92e9/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::8a96:4eff:fe19:63b0
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fd2d:9091:5573:1::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 2600:1700:67b2:36a0::/60, nh = fe80::8a96:4eff:fe19:63b0, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 2600:1700:67b2:36a0::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::8a96:4eff:fe19:63b0, mt = 20100
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = 2600:1700:67b2:36a0::47/128, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[6]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[7]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2600:1700:67b2:36a0::1
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_domain_search = attlocal.net
DHCP6.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = 2600:1700:67b2:36a0::1
DHCP6.OPTION[3]:                        ip6_address = 2600:1700:67b2:36a0::47
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/1
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   6ab51d0b-c1ad-3105-9293-afaab89a26d1 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: Permission denied

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Chicago (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (6, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp4s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp4s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188fu.conf]
options rtl8188fu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

With the ethernet connected, please open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t) and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git
cd rtl8812au/
sudo make dkms_install
```

Detach the ethernet and reboot. You will probably need to disable Secure Boot in the EFI/BIOS.

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: chili555 Awesome! Thank you!!! Disabling Secure Boot in the EFI/BIOS was not required. I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: Awesome, indeed! Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: How is `aircrack-ng` related to not detecting the wifi adapter?

Comment: @FrankNocke aircrack has a driver for his device at github. If you need further clarification, please start your own new question.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, this solution is working but just once. After every wake up from suspend, ubuntu gives this error again,

Comment: @faranjit Please start your own new question.