# Realtek 8812AU / 8821AU wireless driver for Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, realtek-wireless, 20.10

I have little linux experience and am wondering if anyone can help me with this?
I have a Realtek 8812AU / 8821AU USB wifi dongle and am needing the drivers for it so I don't have to be tethered to my router. I've tried using make, git clone, and DKMS to clone repos and build the drivers, and when I've gotten some to show up and be selected in Ubuntu's Software & Updates additional drivers panel, the adapter still never works (when it is in use a blue light flashes). How can I get it to work?

Here is some info:

typing lsusb:

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 04d9:a096 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c08b Logitech, Inc. G502 SE HERO Gaming Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek 8812AU/8821AU 802.11ac WLAN Adapter [USB Wireless Dual-Band Adapter 2.4/5Ghz]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

ifconfig:

```
enp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.111  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::c359:a278:e1b5:db83  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2605:a601:aa70:5500:6219:62f8:1dc0:d75d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:a601:aa70:5500:a045:24ef:8c9d:5636  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether a8:a1:59:35:e7:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 227570  bytes 297235969 (297.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 7  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 111209  bytes 10197829 (10.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1363  bytes 136875 (136.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1363  bytes 136875 (136.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: 0bda:0811 you say? Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294260/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-ubuntu-20-04/1294273#1294273

Comment: Nope, didn't work, I don't know why this doesn't work, is there something else I can try?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe 88XXau` and: `dmesg | grep -i rtl` and `rfkill list all` You may need to disable secure boot in the EFI/BIOS.

Comment: Edit your question and show us `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`. @chili555 first comment should work.

Comment: It's fine, i'm just going to buy a new adapter with official drivers, thanks for the help though

Comment: Getting it to work should be simple but I need the requested diagnostics to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread early, then tried 2 hours of repositories to get a working driver.  8812bu - different chipset

The morrownr github repository works on 20.10 - 19 May 2021
(it also works on rtl88xxxu chipsets from documentation)

Install commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo install -y dkms git
sudo apt install -y dkms git
mkdir src
cd src
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu.git
cd 88x2bu/
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

lsusb:
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL88x2bu [AC1200 Techkey]

uname-a:
Linux  5.8.0-53-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 07:46:32 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Per repo latest, there's a new repo `git clone https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. The realtek driver 8821AU disappeared after an upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04. I followed the driver (re)installation steps in link below,

[Driver for 8821AU here](https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708)

The Wifi driver is back in action working well.

(Just thought it may help)