# Correcting driver installation for rtl8811au dongle

Tags: drivers, wireless, 22.04, dongle

I've had several partially successful attempts at installing this USB dongle on Lubuntu 22.04. It's working now, but may not survive the next reboot. I most recently followed instructions in

https://github.com/morrownr/8821au-20210708#readme

but think I have extra drivers from earlier attempts. When I execute the following:

```
sudo dkms status
```

the output is:

```
rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.15.0-67-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821au/5.12.5.2, 5.15.0-67-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821cu/5.12.0.4, 5.15.0-67-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I suspect some of this needs to be deleted, but I don't know which parts or how to do it.

Can you help, or tell me what else to look at?

Here's the output requested:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard SK-8115
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 09da:0006 A4Tech Co., Ltd. Optical Mouse WOP-35 / Trust 450L Optical Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek 8812AU/8821AU 802.11ac WLAN Adapter [USB Wireless Dual-Band Adapter 2.4/5Ghz]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Thanks, Brian

Still working, but lsmod | grep -e rtl -e 8812 doesn't show any output, my terminal screen just returns to the prompt.

Comment: I suggest that you remove the driver(s) that don't pertain to your exact device. Let's see what you have. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Is it still working after reboot? If so, please show us: `lsmod | grep -e rtl -e 8812` The correct procedure is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294260/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: "lsmod | grep -e rtl -e 8812 doesn't show any output" What does this tell us? `lsmod`